# getting index element

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I have two vectors

```
g_counter = [2 0]
```

and

```
list = [3 0]
```

I would get this:

1. select all the elements of `g_counter` that have the corrisponding values equals to zero in `list` vector.

`2` has the corresponding value in `list` vector not to zero so I will not get it. I will get `0` that have the corresponding value in `list` vector equals to zero

```
0
```

1. getting the index of this element in `g_counter` vector.

   2

Comment: I could not understand your question. Can you add another or lengthier example?

Comment: @Richard I had explained everything

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I disagree, @Mazzy, I still don't understand what you're going for, but I'm interested in helping. If you think you've explained it well enough, I'll just leave it for someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've understood you should do something like that:

```
zeros=find(list==0);
g_counter(zeros) %this will print the values for which the index is 0 in the vector list
```

Comment: Unfortunately  this print 0 and not 2 that it is the corresponding index in g_counter

Comment: I had interpreted the question in the way Maroun85 did. Perhaps if you provide several examples showing your desired outputs.

Comment: It's possible that you are thinking Matlab uses zero-indexed arrays, @Mazzy. If this were the case, then Maroun85's response would give 2 rather than 0 as an output. You could try using `g_counter(zeros-1)` and see if that gives what you want.